# Cannot find module 'node_modules/formidable'

Tags: node.js, formidable

In Node.js I was trying to use formidable module but I am always getting error

```
**Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/formidable'**
```

Details of error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>node E:\NODE_JS\App1\index.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/formidable'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\NODE_JS\App1\requestHandlers.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I have tried to install the module in two way, using the following command

```
npm install formidable
npm install -g formidable
```

And when I run the command (above two) to install formidable the result was

```
C:\Users\Piccaza>npm install formidable
formidable@1.0.15 node_modules\formidable

C:\Users\Piccaza>npm install -g formidable
formidable@1.0.15 C:\Users\Piccaza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\formidable
```

I have installed nodejs in location  `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

And my project location is `E:\NODE_JS\App1`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `index.js` file?  It looks like you're requiring "node_modules/formidable" instead of "formidable"

Comment: Actually I am requiring that from my requestHandler.js file.
//var formidable = require("node_modules/formidable");
//var formidable = require("formidable");
I tried in both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install a package via `npm install`, you don't need to require the file with a full path to the file.  Instead, simply require the package.

So instead of using:

```
var formidable = require("node_modules/formidable");
```

Change instead to use:

```
var formidable = require("formidable");
```

As a note, if you require local files you will need to specify the full path to those files.  [You can view the algorithm that is used to lookup files here.](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)